# Why don't proxyHost/proxyPort work when running my Java application?

Tags: java, fiddler

I have a java app that talks to some REST services, and I want to look at the HTTP traffic using Fiddler.

Fiddler acts as a proxy on localhost:8888, so the following Java VM options are supposed to configure java to use this proxy:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
```

However, if I pass these parameters when running the java app that I want to debug, I see no traffic in Fiddler.

I wrote a test Java app that simply performs an HTTP GET using HttpURLConnection.

I can view the HTTP traffic from this app in fiddler, if I specify the above-mentioned command-line parameters when debugging it from Eclipse.

What are the reasons that http.proxyHost/Port might not work for all java HTTP operations?

Comment: What is the version of java you are running? Run java -version (just in case). Is it a chance that you have the old installation of JRE on your machine? These properties are supported since java 1.5

Comment: The version reported on the command-line is 1.6.0_26. The options do work when debugging my small test app in Eclipse.

Comment: (1) check which JRE are you using with eclipse. Is it the same one that is used when you are running from command line? (2) Did you try to run the small test (that works from eclipse) from command line? If not try it first. If does not work print system properties in the beginning of your test. Then could you please post the full command line you are using?

Comment: Good suggestions. I found that the app I want to test is using Apache HTTP client libraries which apparently do not hook into these proxy config command-line settings: http://cephas.net/blog/2007/11/14/java-commons-http-client-and-http-proxies/

Comment: Keep in mind you need `-Dhttps.proxyPort...` with HTTPS.  Note the trailing s in the property name.

Comment: You also need an empty nonProxyHosts : -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=

Answer (score 4):

You can tell HttpClient to honor the JDK system arguments using the below code (HttpClient 4.x).

```
public static final DefaultHttpClient HTTP = new DefaultHttpClient();
ProxySelectorRoutePlanner routePlanner = new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(HTTP.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(),
ProxySelector.getDefault());
HTTP.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
```

Comment: All this has been deprecated for 4.3.  Does anyone know the best way to do this in 4.3.6+?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above you need to do something like this:

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
   .setRoutePlanner(new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(ProxySelector.getDefault())
```

But that will not be enough.

In TL;DR fashion - you also need all three of these system properties:

-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=

The long answer can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/proxying-request-localhost):

As mentioned by Gerard Davison at the link above:

> It can be very convenient when developing to server based application
>   to run them using "localhost" in order to maintain consistency between
>   developer machines. This is normally a good idea but there is a small
>   case where this can cause problems.
>
> Consider if you are running a local http proxy on your machine in
>   order to capture your HTTP traffic. (Cough perhaps even the one in
>   JDeveloper I work on). Then you might run into [Java bug 6737819](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6737819).
>   Basically by default JDK 1.6 was hard coded not to send any request to
>   localhost via a proxy which of course was a bit of a pain. Luckily a
>   workaround was put in where you could put the string "~localhost" in
>   your nonProxyHosts entry to turn of this feature:
>
> ```
> java -client -classpath classes 
> -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost 
> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8099 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=~localhost 
> -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost 
> -Dhttps.proxyPort=8099 client.Example
> ```
>
> Now moving forward to JDK 1.7 this workaround no longer works; but you
>   need to take care to define nonProxyHosts as an empty string:
>
> ```
> java -client -classpath classes 
> -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost 
> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8099 
> -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts= 
> -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost 
> -Dhttps.proxyPort=8099 client.Example
> ```
>
> If you define this any anything other than an empty string the
>   DefaultProxySelector though beware because internally it will append /
>   or use the http.nonProxyHosts value from ../jre/lib/net.properties".
>
> Just a minor complication that is not obvious from the published API.

Answer (score 2):

For 4.3.6 I used

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort")), "http");//System.getProperty("http.proxyHost")
DefaultRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();
```

Comment: That will work, but if the values of `http.proxyHost` or `http.proxyPort` change while the program is running, that method will not notice the change.  You can use `SystemDefaultRoutePlanner` for a version that will adapt automatically.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache httpclient 4.3.6, it seems that you should use SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.

```
SystemDefaultRoutePlanner routePlanner = new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(null);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
  .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
  .build();
```

This will pick up the proxy settings from system properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`, and will use the current settings of those values each time a new http request is sent.